# Animate a table row out in MeteorJS

Tags: jquery, css, animation, meteor, coffeescript

I've got a sort of cart where when new items are added they fade in from the top, this works fine.
However when I try to jquery the item to fade out, it seems like meteor is removing the item before it can animate out and it gets this very ugly flash out.

Below is the coffescript for removing an item, I've tried to add a delay after the animation should fire, but this doesn't work. I'm using animate.css and wow.

I've deployed the site to [stackoverflowrocks.meteor.com](http://stackoverflowrocks.meteor.com) so you can see what I mean.

Thanks alot in advance

```
'click .btnminus': (e, template) ->
            #console.log(event.target);
            value = $(event.target).attr('data')
            if Order.findOne(name: value).quantity > 1
                Order.update { name: value }, $inc: quantity: -1
            else
                $(event.target).parent().parent().removeClass('fadeInDown').addClass('fadeOutUp').delay(800)
                Order.remove name: value
```

Answer (score 0):

Meteor has some [UI hooks](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/1kUoG2mcaRw) for this purpose that allow you to tie in to the rendering engine. It's almost impossible to do this at the helper level. These aren't well documented, but they've been around since 0.8.0.

I've written a package that does fading in and out automatically for a `{{#each}}` block: https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-animated-each

You can play with a demo at http://animated-each.meteor.com/. These examples should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Thanks, I've installed the package you linked + Jquery UI and added a div container for the each and attached the hook in my script. But I can't see any change at all.
And on the example you posted I also can't see any animations, I'm running the latest version of chrome. The only part which fades is the x on the button.

Comment: I'm also using the latest version of chrome, and both fading in and fading out works on the demo for me. What happens if you visit the demo in a different browser?

Also, just to be sure: are you **clicking** the red X buttons in the demo?

Comment: The demo is working working in Firefox on my pc and Mac, and chrome on my pc strange, going to reinstall chrome.